# How to solve a second order partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this partial differential equation: $$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}y(x,t)-\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}y(x,t)=\frac{A}{t^{2}}y(x,t)$$
With $A \in \mathbb{R}$. I would like to find the more general analytical solution to this with unfixed integration constants. I am not a mathematician so I am not even sure if this is possible. If it were not: is it possible to prove that such a solution exists? Thank you for the help!
(As I said above: I'm not a mathematician, so be kind!)

Comment: Without initial condition they are an infinity of solutions, some involving Bessel functions.

Comment: @JJacquelin, so there is not a solution that can comprehend all of them? Anyway, if I specified some boundary conditions (independently on what they are), there would be possible to find a solution? If yes, how can I prove it?

Comment: The general solution can be expressed as a sum of particular solutions. They are an infinity of different particular solutions. If some conditions are specified one can expect to find a convenient linear combination of particular solutions which satisfy the PDE and the specified solutions. But one cannot prove that it is always possible since the possiblity depends on the kind of conditions. Of course the general solution exists but this doesn't mean that one can express it analytically with a finite number of standard functions.

Comment: Thank you! And how can I prove that the general solution exists?

Comment: This is a question too wide to be treated on a forum. First study the theory of PDEs and become familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}y(x,t)-\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}y(x,t)=\frac{A}{t^{2}}y(x,t)$$
An infinity of particular solutions can be found thanks to the separation of variables method. We look for particular solutions on the form $y(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ where $X(x)$ and $T(t)$ are unknown functions.
$$X''T-XT''=\frac{A}{t^{2}}XT$$
$$\frac{X''}{X}-\frac{T''}{T}=\frac{A}{t^{2}}$$
$$\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=\frac{T''(t)}{T(t)}+\frac{A}{t^{2}}=z^2$$
$z$ is an arbitrary complex (or real) constant.

A function of $x$ and a function of $t$ can be equal any $x,t$ only if both are equal to a common constant.
$$X''(x)-z^2X(x)=0\quad\implies\quad X(x)=e^{\pm z\;x}$$
This includes a lot of functions of mixed exponential and sinusoidal functions.
$$T''(t)+\left(\frac{A}{t^2}-z^2\right)T(t)=0$$
This is an ODE of Bessel kind which solution is :
$$T(t)=c_1\sqrt{t}\:I_\nu(z\;t)+c_2\sqrt{t}\:K_\nu(z\;t)\quad ; \quad \nu=\sqrt{1-4A}$$
$I$ and $K$ denote the modified Bessel functions.

Now a lot of particular solutions are known with arbitrary complex or real constants $z,c_1,c_2$ :

$$y=e^{\pm z\;x}\left(c_1\sqrt{t}\:I_\nu(z\;t)+c_2\sqrt{t}\:K_\nu(z\;t \right)$$

A more wide solution is made of any linear combination of those particular solutions :
$$y(x,t)=\sqrt{t}\int f(z)e^{\pm z\;x}\:I_\nu(z\;t)dz+\sqrt{t}\int g(z)e^{\pm z\;x}\:K_\nu(z\;t)dz$$
$f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are arbitrary functions.

If some initial condition is specified one can expect to determine the functions $f,g$. In general this is a very difficult task far to be always possible. However, if you are lucky with the initial condition, it is possible but rarely that the solution be much simpler than the above equation.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really helpful.